# PHP authenticating bb code

Tags: php, bbcode

I have an image mysite.com/images/img1.png
i want to show image in bb code

```
[img]mysite.com/images/img1.png[/img]
```

but only for person who enter login and pass.

This auth form:

```
<?php
  function  authenticate()  {
    setcookie("noauth","");
    Header( "WWW-authenticate:  Basic realm=\"test\"");
    Header( "HTTP/1.0  401  Unauthorized");
    echo " ";
   exit ;
  }
  if  (   !isset($PHP_AUTH_USER) ||  ($logoff==1) && $noauth=="yes"  )   {
    authenticate();
  } 
?>
```

I can't do image throw auth form.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that you cannot have PHP code in an image file.

With a default setup a user can go to the URL and the image will be displayed.

There are two options here, both which involve the use of `htaccess`:

1) Deny requests for the image and access it by a handler page.

2) Route requests for the image to a handler file.

Basic PHP code for outputting image:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile('/images/img1.png'');
```